# QT Unable to draw box on screen (QRect and QRubberBand)

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, screenshot, xlib

I'm trying to write a tool in C++ that will help me with my language study. It will capture an area on the screen (a word or sentence), process the text, then display information on the captured text in a GUI application.

This is a basic diagram of what I'm trying to do:
[image]

This is supposed to be very similar to screen capture tools like gnome-screenshot and Microsoft's snipping tool on Windows.

A third party application is something like a pdf viewer or image viewer that contains scan-able text. My application displays information about the captured text. My application also draws a resizable 'capture window' on the screen, shown by the red box that surrounds a word in the diagram.

My question is about drawing this red box on the screen. How can I draw a red box on the screen? I've been trying to do this with both xLib and QT, though I would prefer to do it with QT since it's better documented and cross-platform.

edit: I modified the question to make it more concise and clear to my objective, and how the accepted answer solves my issue.

Comment: Your issue may be what you mean by box on screen.  Do you mean a (mostly) transparent, borderless window over your word?  What should happen to this box when the word moves on the screen?  How will your program know to update the box?

Comment: `I failed to get GTK working for me, I couldn't get an example compiled` You gave up too quickly, how about `apt-get install gtkmm`? at least you would deal with C++ library.

Comment: I've found some good examples for taking a screen shot, it seems like qt is able to do this. I can them crop the image based on the size of the rectangle on the screen. But, I can't seem to draw a rectangle on screen, which is the part that is frustrating me. Yes, a mostly transparent box with a small border. When box is made on the word, I capture the text to image, my program will take the image on a key press that I'll define at a later point.

Comment: And yes, I gave up early on GTK. But, I don't want to invest time into this if it turns out to be a waste of time because I'm thinking about my problem wrong.

Comment: When I read the title of your question I imagined someone either trying to draw boxes with ASCII, or someone trying some graphic/game library to draw boxes. In both cases it would only be in the window created by your C++ application. IMHO you could
have more chances of an answer with a title such as "capturing screen text with C++", or something similar. That is, something that makes clear you want to intercept what is written by other applications.

Comment: I updated the title. But none the less, the major issue I'm trying to get answered with this question is "How the hell do I draw a box on the screen?" Regardless of functionality that it will lead to later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a frameless, alwaysOnTop window that contains a widget. The window should be defined as having a translucent background, whereas the widget will be used to display the border (or semi-opaque background). You can then manipulate the position and size of the window through code by detecting mouse clicks on your window that opens the pdf.

Here's an example:

[image: demo image]

The code:

```
QMainWindow window;
window.setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
window.setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true);
window.setFixedSize(80, 20);
window.move(500,500);

QWidget widget(&window);
widget.setStyleSheet("border: 3px solid rgb(255,0,0)");

window.setCentralWidget(&widget);
window.show();
```

Comment: :D:D That works perfectly! This is exactly the guidance I needed, thank you!

Comment: After developing my code a bit using this as the foundation for my work I noticed that my window isn't transparent without a composistor running. I run Linux with i3-gaps and compton for a compositor. This makes me concerned for moving towards cross-platform later. Will this solution work with MacOS and Windows? Do most Linux distributions come with compositors?

I also switched my approach a bit. Now I have a screen sized transparent window, and I'm using QRubberBand to draw the capture box on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is the preferred solution to this question, but after answering this question I found an example project that accomplished what I was going for using xlib.

https://github.com/gvalkov/xrectsel

I included this for completeness, but the QT solution has better API and is cross-platform. So, this better suits my needs for this program.